# How to test a function which is returned within an object in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, canvas, jestjs, html2canvas

I want to test my util function which contains options for generating canvas via html2canvas,

```
const getCanvasOptions = () => {
  const { devicePixelRatio } = window;
  const { scrollHeight, scrollWidth } = document.body;
  const ratio = devicePixelRatio < 2 ? devicePixelRatio : devicePixelRatio / 2;
  const width = scrollWidth * ratio;
  const height = scrollHeight * ratio;
  return {
    allowTaint: true,
    letterRendering: 1,
    foreignObjectRendering: true,
    quality: 1,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    scale: ratio,
    useCORS: true,
    ignoreElements: (node) => {
      return node.nodeName === 'NOSCRIPT';
    }
  };
};
```

I am testing it by mocking the `document` and `window` object, and then `strictEqual` check of `expected` and `actual` returned object. But in my coverage, it shows that the below line is untested,

```
return node.nodeName === 'NOSCRIPT'
```

How can I test the above line in jest?

Comment: if code coverage is the target, maybe a test case that invokes the `ignoreElements` method could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `ignoreElements` method after invoking `getCanvasOptions` function in your test case. Then, invoke it and test it as usual.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
export const getCanvasOptions = () => {
  const { devicePixelRatio } = window;
  const { scrollHeight, scrollWidth } = document.body;
  const ratio = devicePixelRatio < 2 ? devicePixelRatio : devicePixelRatio / 2;
  const width = scrollWidth * ratio;
  const height = scrollHeight * ratio;
  return {
    allowTaint: true,
    letterRendering: 1,
    foreignObjectRendering: true,
    quality: 1,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    scale: ratio,
    useCORS: true,
    ignoreElements: (node) => {
      return node.nodeName === 'NOSCRIPT';
    },
  };
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { getCanvasOptions } from './';

describe('67778543', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const actual = getCanvasOptions();
    expect(actual).toEqual({
      allowTaint: true,
      letterRendering: 1,
      foreignObjectRendering: true,
      quality: 1,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      scale: 1,
      useCORS: true,
      ignoreElements: expect.any(Function),
    });
    // test ignoreElements method
    const rval = actual.ignoreElements({ nodeName: 'NOSCRIPT' });
    expect(rval).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67778543/index.test.ts (8.274 s)
  67778543
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 4                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.31 s, estimated 10 s
```